# How can I remove duplicate columns? In a number of columns

Tags: python, sql, duplicates

I'd like to keep rows who are caring only one pet. (kim, choi, lee)
If possible, I would appreciate it if you could tell me both for sql and Python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zxwU.png)

Comment: Show us your code, including your SQL query.  You can certainly do this by using `COUNT(name)` and `WHERE COUNT(name) == 1`.  Also, please paste your data as text, not as an image.

Comment: Can you explain your issue in a better way. An output example can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your table structure as on image:

```
create table tbl(
 name text,
 pet text,
 age int
)
```

You can do such query:

```
select name, age from tbl
group by name, age
having (count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379419/how-can-ihandle-duplicates-on-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

try this one
I have used nested query

```
select * from <table>
where name in 
(select name from <table> group by name having count(*)=1)
```

the second part:-
`(select name from <table> group by name having count(*)=1)`
is for finding the name from the table
and the first one is used to select all data from the table with the given name