# How can Ihandle duplicates on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'd like to get rows with ID and name matching 1:1 as a result. As you can see in the dataframe bellow, James has multiple IDs. And I would like to assume that these duplicate rows are errors and exclude them from the final output.

```html
id  name    pet
1   Tom cat
4   James   cat
5   James   dog
5   James   tiger
2   Lee bird
3   Alex    dog
3   Alex    bird
```

I expect output like :

```html
id  name    pet
1   Tom cat
2   Lee bird
3   Alex    dog
3   Alex    bird
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I think you should rather overthink your whole database. Having an ID defined twice is wrong in any case. Two different entries should never share an ID. Rather define your primary keys properly to avoid this problem completely.

To fix your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM SO
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a7da4/1)

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` usually indicated broken code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: . . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e579ccda657e832e408343ef823a17e5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    p.Id,
    x.Name,
    p.Pet
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Name
    FROM
        Pets
    GROUP BY 
        Name
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS x
JOIN Pets [p] ON p.Name = x.Name
```

Basically we are using a subquery to grab any names that exist exactly once in the table, and then joining the result of the subquery back to the table on the `Name` column. Note: In your sample output, 'Alex' was listed twice. This will filter out 'Alex' because that is a duplicate name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```